# how to call FragmentActivity for selected nav drawer list item fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Helo.
I has just look at androidhive.info and get the code SlideMenu. And now I integrate SlideMenu with TabBar.
This is my code of SlideMenu Fragment to get select :

```
/**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break; 

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

And now at my HomeFrament:

```
public abstract class HomeFragment extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };
```

and I got the error:

> Cannot instantiate the type HomeFragment

How Can I integrade my Fragment with FragmentActivity ? please help me. Thanks.